# What led to or what leads to?

Tags: british-english, sentence

Which of the following sentences below is correct? Examples:

1. What leads to World War or what led to World War?
2. What led to the invention of computers or what lead to the invention of computers?

Comment: Both things you refer to happened in the past, so why would you not use the past tense?

Comment: As @KateBunting says both your examples are of things which happened in the past so 'led to' is generally more appropriate. "Leads to" and "lead to" are usually used for more current and repeated situations. For instance "Drinking alcohol before driving leads to traffic accidents", "Neglect of hand hygiene leads to disease", "Gambling and poor budgeting lead to personal debt"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether it is present or past tense. if you are saying, "what leads to World war?" you are asking a question about what currently leads to world war. But if you ask, "What led to world war?" then you are asking about a past world war and the causes leading up to it.

For #2 it would be what led to the invention of computers? because the other option is what lead to the invention of computers?, and the phrase what lead is grammatically incorrect.